# How to return an object from a class, and what exactly is this object when a constructor creates a new HashMap?

Tags: java, class, hashmap, instance

I've been doing bunch of exercises and it kinda all made sense, but when I had to write the code from scratch myself suddenly I'm so confused, if anyone would help me out a bit, that would be great.

I have:

```
public class Airplane {
  private HashMap<String,Integer> plane;
  public Airplane() {
    this.plane = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  }
  public addAirplane(String id, int capacity) {
    this.plane.put(id,capacity);


 public class Flight {
   private HashMap<Airplane, List<String>> flight;
   public Flight() {
     this.flight = new HashMap<Airplane,List<String>>();
   public addFlight(Airplane airplane, String departurePort, String destinationPort) {
     this.flight.put(airplane, Arrays.asList(departurePort, destinationPort));
    }
```

Then I have another class where I create instances of both Plane and Flight,

```
private Airplane airplane = new Airplane();
private Flight flight = new Flight();
```

and for the most part it seems to work alright, however I cannot figure out what am I supposed to retrieve and add here..

I read plane ID and two airport codes from the user, and I want to do something like this:

```
flight.addFlight( //here I have Airplane's name//, departureAirport, destinationAirport);
```

So basically two questions: 1) How do I retrieve "Airplane" object when having only its name.
2) What exactly is this "Airplane" object? Is it HashMap? Is it an instance of HashMap? Is there a difference if I try to pass HashMap instead of Airplane to the the method flight.addFlight(Airplane,String,String)?

Comment: you `Airplane` and `Flight` instance shouldn´t be containing maps. They should contain the `id` and the `capacity`, which should get passed in the constructor. You actually would want to have two more classes that contain the `Map<String, Airplane>`, including the `id` is unique. There you want to store instances of `Airplane` and `Flight`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. It breaks off in the middle of a method and then starts defining a class. Could you post less fragmentary code if you are posting code please?

Comment: @khelwood I truncated it, as I mentioned the code does work

Comment: @KevinEsche yes.. you are right, it's as if I forgot everything I learned before.

Comment: It seems you have codes without thinking of what you needs and without writing a nice class diagram. Here, it seems you want to store Airplane with a String id into the Airplane instance (the map) but an Airplane should not be linked to other Airplane, you probably miss a class like `Airport` or `Air Company` or `Control tower` ... that will contains every `Airplane` in a map. **So, I would suggest to rethink a bit your code, you have rush on your keyboard probably (rookie mistake ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll try to explain what you wanted to achieve. Just check if this is what you really wanted.

Say you want to design an application for a airport. Let's keep it very simple at this point of time. You can extend it later for your own use cases.

Let's start designing your application.

Every `Airport` has `Flights` and it has facilities to operate on those flights. Hence, a simple class design of Airport and Flight and related objects is as shown:

```
public class Airport {
    private List<Flight> allFlights;

    public List<Flight> getAllFlights() {
        return allFlights;
    }

    public void setAllFlights(List<Flight> allFlights) {
        this.allFlights = allFlights;
    }

    /**
     * Add flights
     * @param flight
     */
    public void addFlights(Flight flight){
        allFlights.add(flight);
    }

    /**
     * Delete flights
     * @param flight
     */
    public void deleteFlight(Flight flight){
        for(Flight eachFlight : allFlights){
            if(eachFlight.equals(flight)){
                allFlights.remove(eachFlight);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update specific flight info.
     * 
     * @param flightId
     * @param airplane
     * @param source
     * @param destination
     * @return
     */
    public boolean updateFlight(long flightId, Airplane airplane, String source, String destination){
        boolean isUpdated = false;
        for(Flight eachFlight : allFlights){
            if(eachFlight.getFlightId() == flightId){
                eachFlight.setAirplane(airplane);
                eachFlight.setSourceName(source);
                eachFlight.setDestinationName(destination);
                isUpdated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isUpdated;
    }
}
```

Every `Flight` has a `Airplane` along with source and destination
Flight and Airplane are just Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs)

```
public class Flight {
    private long flightId;
    private Airplane airplane;
    private String sourceName;
    private String destinationName;

    public long getFlightId() {
        return flightId;
    }

    public void setFlightId(long flightId) {
        this.flightId = flightId;
    }

    public Airplane getAirplane() {
        return airplane;
    }

    public void setAirplane(Airplane airplane) {
        this.airplane = airplane;
    }

    public String getSourceName() {
        return sourceName;
    }

    public void setSourceName(String sourceName) {
        this.sourceName = sourceName;
    }

    public String getDestinationName() {
        return destinationName;
    }

    public void setDestinationName(String destinationName) {
        this.destinationName = destinationName;
    }

    //Override equals method
}

public class Airplane {
    private long id;
    private String make;
    private String airlinesCompany;

    public Airplane(long id, String make, String airlinesCompany) {
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.airlinesCompany = airlinesCompany;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getAirlinesCompany() {
        return airlinesCompany;
    }
}
```

I hope this design clears your idea.